# HTTP Status Code 400 or 422 if data type mismatched for a request value?

Tags: http-status-code-400, http-status-code-422

HTTP Status Code 400 or 422 if data type mismatched for a request value? Is it correct to use 400 in below cases or 422 should be used instead?

1. A String value received in header, path or query parameter where an Integer is expected
2. A String value received in JSON body for an attribute where an Integer is expected

Comment: Personally, I would use 400 for both. 422 means the syntax of the entity is correct but the server is choosing to not process the entity, but that is not the case here since the entity's data is just plain wrong. But, that is just my *opinion*.  And as such, I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based, which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow.

Comment: I used the same as you suggested. Happy to know that people agree with me

Answer (score 2):

RFC2616, gave the use of 400 (Bad Request)

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
> syntax

In my opinion data type mismatch should be considered as *malformed syntax*, therefore, 400 is an appropriate option in above case.